# Interactive dictionary programm in python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have built an interactive dictionary: the programm requires an input from the user(a word) and as an output it gives a definition of the input word:

For this I have a dictionary, where keys are words and values are their definitions.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import re

data = json.load(open('C:\\Users\\yefida\\Desktop\\Study_folder\\Online_Courses\\python mega course\\Project1 - Interactive Dictionary\\data.json'))

def interactive_dict(input_user):
    input_user = input_user.lower()
    for key in data.keys():
        my_regex = r'^[a-z0-9_]*' +  key + '[a-z0-9_]*$' 
        if input_user == key:
            for values in data[key]:
                print(values)
            break
        elif bool(re.match(my_regex,input_user)):
            check = input('Do you mean {}? If yes type "y", if no type "n":'.format(key))
            if check == 'y':
                for values in data[key]:
                    print(values)
                break


interactive_dict('dain')
```

In most cases it works good, but:

1. For example, I provided as an input the word "dain" (which doesn't exist) and it starts checking in the dictionary(based on regex code) the following words: "a", 'in" , which of course are far away from the truth.
2. When the word isn't contained in the dctionary, the programm returns me an error: **"error: bad character range o-K at position 14"**

Can you help me to solve this two issues? Any further improvments of the code are higly appreciated as well.

Dictionary can be found here: https://github.com/adambom/dictionary

Comment: Iterating through the dictionary keys defeats the point of dictionaries. You need only check whether the value is `input_user.lower() in data` or use `data.get(input_user.lower())`

Comment: That's half true, your first statement should be if key in data:
return data[key]
else:
 Iterate through keys to help user

Answer (score 1):

There is something odd with your regex, also there is no point in iterating through the keys the first time (like @roganjosh said), just check if the key is in there.

```
def interactive_dict(data, input_user):
    input_user = input_user.lower()
    if input_user in data:
        [print(value) for value in data[input_user]]
    else:
        my_regex = r'^[a-z0-9_]*' +  input_user + '[a-z0-9_]*$' 
        for key in data:
            if bool(re.match(my_regex, key)):
                check = input('Do you mean {}? If yes type "y", if no type "n":'.format(key))
                if check == 'y':
                    for values in data[key]:
                        print(values)
                    break

data = json.load(open('your file'))
interactive_dict(data, 'dain')
```

The point is, you are matching incorrectly if I understood your question, you want to check what keys in your dictionary contain the user_input, not the other way around. e.g if user says eleph he probably means elephant or telephone (is that right?) That's what the change in the regex does.

Comment: But in second case(else), probably you forgot the for loop, because you have to iterate through the keys in order to find the match, Am i right?

Comment: Yes. This is a minor error in the code. The regex pattern needs to be defined inside of the key iteration loop and needs to include the `key` in the pattern instead of the `input_user`

Comment: No. You Want to. Check whether the key contains the input not the other way aroubd

Comment: Yes for got the for loop. Edited

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
import re

data = {'dain': [1,2,3,4]}

def interactive_dict(input_user: str):
    input_user = input_user.lower()
    master_key = None
    if input_user in data:
        master_key = input_user
    else:
        for key in data:
            my_regex = re.compile(fr""" # f-string + raw string (fr)
                \w*                     # \w is a predefined character class. Short for [a-zA-Z0-9_]
                {key}                   # with f-strings the variable name goes between the template tags
                \w*                     # 0 or more word characters
                """, re.VERBOSE         # verbose mode flag
            )
            if my_regex.match(key):
                check = input(f'Do you mean {key}? If yes type "y", if no type "n":')
                if check == 'y':
                    master_key = key
                    break
    if master_key:
        for value in data[master_key]:
            print(value)


interactive_dict('disdain')
```

Comment: Thank you for the anser! Can you please explain, what your regex code does?

Comment: Sure. Have a look at the answer again. I provided notes which break down the pattern.